# Help in specify attribute of dynamic generated table in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am facing a problem to how to add the attributes of table like width, cell spacing.

```
var newTable = $("<table />",{id: 'myTable'+tab_counter});          
newTable.appendTo('#dialog'+tab_counter);
```

if i add in table tag it still doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what's hard here; your code is almost there:

```
$('<table/>', {id: 'myTable' + tab_counter, width: '100%', cellSpacing: '12px'});
```

Comment: @lonesomeday...i have tried this before but it still not working.

Comment: basically i am very new to jquery, so kind of having difficulty in handling syntax. thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can predefine a style, do that.

```
var newTable = $('<table id="myTable'+tab_counter+'" class="myTableCSS"></table>');
```

If you have to do it inline, just do it at generation time:

```
var newTable = $('<table id="myTable'+tab_counter+'" style="width:500px;border-collapse:collapse"></table>');
```

Comment: i have done it with defining a css and it works, but i am wondering why it is not working when i am defining the attributes within table tab.

Comment: Might be time to build a test case post a link to jsfiddle or something.  What you have in your example is incomplete.